# How to Object.create() in a loop?

Tags: javascript

Examples of looping object creation that I find online use the new keyword and I want to use Object.create().

My attempt returns an error at line 29:
https://jsfiddle.net/ynfkev6c/2/

```
function my_game() {
var cols = 11;
var rows = 11;
var num = cols * rows;
var size = 50;
var spacing = 5;

var square = {
    size: 50,
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}

var piece = {
    size: 50,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    name: king
}


function make_grid() {
    var squares = [];
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            squares.push({ // ??
                Object.create(square); // ??
                x: i; // ??
                y: j; // ??
            })
        }
    }
}

}
```

How would you find this answer if you were me?

Comment: Your object literal syntax is wrong. You didn't provide a property name for the created object value, and you're separating properties with semicolons instead of commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `Object.create` inside an object literal. You will need to write

```
function make_grid() {
    var squares = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            var o = Object.create(square);
            o.x = i;
            o.y = j;
            squares.push(o);
        }
    }
    return squares;
}
```

or if you need a more concise solution without a temporary variable,

```
squares.push(Object.assign(Object.create(square), { 
    x: i,
    y: j,
}));
```

Comment: Object.assign is new to me like most of javascript, but it doesn't involve creating a new temporary variable and it just works, so thanks!

While this answers the question as asked, @Andy answer pointed out the idea to just make a create_square() function and add that to the array, which I think is the best practice (but I'm very new to javascript)

Comment: @Gallaxhar Putting the construction in a function might be useful depending on how often you need it, but it's functionally equivalent. You still would need to place the same code in that function - whether using `Object.create` with a temp variable, `Object.create` with `Object.assign`, or a plain object literal without any inheritance (which I think is not what you wanted).

Answer (score 1):

Change your inner loops like that:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        let sq = Object.create(square)
        sq.x = i
        sq.y = j
        squares.push(sq)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! there is no way to avoid creating the sq variable? Can I put the Object.create and the .x and .y inside the squares.push()?

Answer (score 1):

I might use a function to create the object by passing in the `i` and `j` parameters and just push that to the array:

```
function createSquare(x, y) {
  return { size: 50, x, y }
}

...

for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
  squares.push(createSquare(i, j));
}
```

Comment: thanks again Andy, you ended up giving me the answer I didn't know to ask for
https://jsfiddle.net/ynfkev6c/21/

Answer (score 0):

**Create the object and then either set or assign the properties:**

```
var obj = Object.create(square);
squares.push(Object.assign(obj, {x: i, y: j }));
```

**Or set the properties:**

```
var obj = Object.create(square);
obj.x = i;
obj.y = j;
squares.push(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in `squares.push`, you begin object notation, which expects commas, not semicolons between keys:

```
squares.push({ // ??
    Object.create(square); // ??
    x: i; // ??
    y: j; // ??
})

// should be

squares.push({
    // Object.create(square), // we'll address this in a bit
    x: i,
    y: j,
})
```

Furthermore, I'm not sure if you intend on just pushing the new Object or merging in the values `x: i, y: j` but you can do the first easily:

```
squares.push(Object.create(square))
```

Or the second easily if you have ES6 support:

```
// This will merge the created object with the new values 
squares.push({
    ...square,
    x: i,
    y: j,
})
```

Comment: No, spread syntax does not work here. The created object would not inherit from `square` as it should.

Comment: Uh, the object literal with spread syntax still doesn't prototypically inherit from `square`

Comment: https://es6console.com/jeyfppkb/
this says 'unexpected token' at the ...square, line. It doesn't do it for me unless I toggle/untoggle ES2015 and ES2016 on the left, though.

Answer (score 0):

`squares.push({...})` will create array of objects.Each object will need key and value. `squares.push({Object.create(square);` is neither creating a key or value

That snippet can be replaced by

```
squares.push({ // ??
          'a': Object.create(square), // ??
          x: i, // ??
          y: j, // ??
        })
```

Full snippet

```
function my_game() {
  var cols = 11;
  var rows = 11;
  var num = cols * rows;
  var size = 50;
  var spacing = 5;

  var square = {
    size: 50,
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }

  var piece = {
    size: 50,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    name: king
  }


  function make_grid() {
    var squares = [];
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        squares.push({ // ??
          'a': Object.create(square), // ??
          x: i, // ??
          y: j, // ??
        })
      }
    }
    console.log(squares)
  }

}
```